# how to write conditional query from two tables using LINQ

Tags: linq

There are two tables in two database
Promotion: code, source, broker
BrokerNo: Id, Name, BrokerNo
What I want to query are all BrokerNo.Name records satisfying the condition of Promotion.broker=BrokerNo.BrokerNo and Promotion.source="asdf"
How to write the query statement using LINQ?

Comment: Can you not make it a foreign key, then by using linq in your entities you will have access to the Object directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from promotion in Promotion
from brokerNo in BrokerNo
where promotion.source == "asdf" && promotion.broker == brokerNo.BrokerNo
select brokerNo.Name
```